# Generics: How do I implement an hierarchical interface correctly?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, hierarchy

The following code does not compile. What changes to TestRowViewModel or BucketT would I need to get this working? I just can´t seem to wrap my head around this.

```
public interface IBase
{
    public string BaseContent { get; }
}

public interface IHierarchy<T> : IBase
    where T : IBase
{
    public List<T> Children { get; }
}

public class TestRowViewModel1 : IHierarchy<TestRowViewModel1>, IBase
{
    public List<TestRowViewModel1> Children => [...];

    public string BaseContent => [...];
}

public class TestRowViewModel2 : IHierarchy<IBase>, IBase
{
    public List<IBase> Children => [...];

    public string BaseContent => [...];
}

public class BucketConfig
{
    public List<BucketT<IHierarchy<IBase>>> BucketList { get; } = new List<BucketT<IHierarchy<IBase>>>();

    public BucketConfig()
    {
        var test1 = new BucketT<TestRowViewModel1>(); // [1]
        var test2 = new BucketT<TestRowViewModel2>(); // Compiles
        this.BucketList.Add(test1);                   // [2]
        this.BucketList.Add(test2);                   // [3]
   }
}

public class BucketT<T>
    where T : IHierarchy<IBase>, IBase
{

}
```

> [1] Fails with CS0311: TestRowViewModel1 cannot be used as type parameter '`T`' in the generic type or method '`BucketT<T>`'. There is no implicit reference conversion from `TestRowViewModel1` to `IHierarchy<IBase>`

> [2] Fails with CS1503: Cannot convert `TestRowViewModel1` to `BucketT<IHierarchy< IBase>>`

> [3] Fails with CS1503: Cannot convert `TestRowViewModel2` to `BucketT<IHierarchy< IBase>>`

Comment: Just because two types exhibit a particular relationship (say A implements B) that doesn't mean that a generic parameterized by those two types exhibits the same relationship (`G<A>` doesn't "implement" or inherit from `G<B>`). A `TestRowViewModel1` is a `IHierarchy<TestRowViewModel1>` but that *isn't* a type derived from `IHierarchy<IBase>`. You can't generally solve these problems except for limited contra- and co-variance escape hatches, and those aren't available to you when you're exposing a `List<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you have an idea how I could solve this in a different way, but also using generics? - no excape hatch wanted :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I edited my question and added a second test case. Why doesn´t [3] compile?

Comment: You could try making your generic interfaces covariant, using `<out T>`, but you would need to use `IReadOnlyList<T>` for `Children` because `List<T>` is invariant. Here's an example that compiles: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9dROpK.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thanks for the input. I tried it out: [1] compiles, but the points [2] and [3] remain. Any ideas? - Oh, I didn´t see the fiddle. I´ll have a look

Comment: @Chris You also need an `IBucketT<out T>` interface, because your `BucketT` class cannot have generic variance.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thanks! I´ll have to see if that code is usable for me with the restrictions of the IReadOnlyList outside of the test case.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Post the fiddle if you want and I´ll mark as answer.